# JTextField loading

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, joptionpane

I'm having a problem..
In my code I have it so that text should output to a JTextField. when I run the program, it doesn't. However, if I directy after my code for putting text into the JTextField put a JOptionPane then it works...

Anyone have an solution to make the JTextField update without having the JOptionPane after?

My code:

```
// Works:
JTextField.setText("String");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "String");

// Doesn't Work:
JTextField.setText("String");
//JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "String");
```

Comment: The example given is too vague to start with. Are you setting text in context of some thread that you started?

Comment: You've got a bug in code that you're not showing us. I wonder if you may have a concurrency issue, as if you were trying to update the JTextField repeatedly perhaps in a loop with a call to Thread.sleep() and that's why it's not showing, but this is nothing but a SWAG til you tell us the details that we need to know.

Comment: I'm not using any threads... But maybe the framework I have does...

Comment: Only guessing is possible here. If you have problem formulate question correctly, you can find help here: http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons why this might fail:

1. You're calling `setText()` from outside the main (Swing) thread
2. You're calling `setText()` from in the main (Swing) thread

In the first case, wrap the call in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

In the latter case, you set the text but you're blocking the Swing thread, so the change can't be rendered. You will need to create a background worker to do the work and use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to update the text field from your worker thread.

**[EDIT]** See the Swing tutorial for an example how to use background thread and how to update the UI from there: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html

Comment: Do you mean like this??

`javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
  JTextField.setText("Connecting you to #TeamZeale as " + n + ", hang on it might take a while...");
 }
});`

Comment: It only works if you're doing all the work in a background thread. If you block the main thread, Swing will never be able to process events and no rendering will happen. The UI will also appear to be "frozen".

Comment: @enjikaka: Please stop making us guess. Please show us more of your code and explain more of what you're doing as many of us have already requested of you.

Comment: I am trying to make is so that when I run the function runBot() in njIRC.class it uses a function in Act.class named putInS(String n) to set the text of the JTextField named status in Main.java to the string I pass in.

Comment: @enjikaka: This is irrelevant. In which thread is this code executed?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use repaint() after the text update?

If memory serves me right that should address the issue of the text not appending.